What's the proper way to handle `process.on('SIGINT'` on node.js?
A typical sample code for handling SIGINT ends with a process.exit, like this:
const closeMyServer = async () => {
  logger.info(`Closing myServer...`);
  await myServer.close();
  logger.info('myServer closed');

  process.exit(0);
};

process.on('SIGINT', () => {
  void closeMyServer();
});

Without the proces.exit, the signal is suppressed, so, like, a CTRL-C will no longer stop the binary. But calling process.exit is very "greedy" -- if there are, like, multiple process.on('SIGINT', only one of them will actually fully execute (whichever one gets to process.exit first).
E.g. if I also have a deleteTempFiles that I want to run when I get a CTRL-C I could try to add:
process.on('SIGINT', () => {
  void deleteTempFiles('SIGINT');
});

But if, say, .close takes 30ms and the deleting all files takes 500ms, as soon as the .close completes, the process is forcefully terminated with process.exit and the deletion of the temp files gets halted.
Is there a proper way to do this, without requiring there to be a single process.on('SIGINT'?

Consider explaining your case. You can queue cleanup jobs yourself without relying on multiple sigint listeners. Or you can move some of them to exit listener, with fs calls being restricted to sync
